# Is it possible to know the mac address or any identification from the user request in DAD?

Tags: switch, ipv6

Is it possible to get an identification like Mac Address in the packet of a DAD attempt that is succesfull? 
or in the NA Message?

I'm trying to narrow down how can I know the client who is replying on the DAD on our network.

Example Scenario: PC1 generated an address and uses DAD protocol, which PC2 then reply but in this case he is attacking PC1 by replying to all NA. My problem is It is possible to get the IPv6 or Mac Address of PC2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only if he isn't lying about (spoofing) his own src address.  Capture the network traffic to see the claimed source (MAC) of the frame, then hunt down where that MAC lives on your switches. (switches will learn MACs based on ingress traffic.)

Comment: Hi, the MAC of the frame where can I find it? I check my NA or NS Packets in wireshark but there is no MAC Frame or am I looking at the wrong packets

Comment: Look in the ethernet header. In wireshark it should be above the IPv6 header

Comment: Hi, I just realize this. What Network Traffic should I be expecting? Or what packet should I get to know the mac address of Attacker?